# Change header text dynamically in React Native

Tags: react-native

My navigationOptions for StackNavigator is:--

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
    return ({
        headerRight: (
            (navigation.state.params.actionTitle)?
                <TouchableOpacity style={{padding: 10}} onPress={() => navigation.state.params.onPressDelete()}>
                    <Text style={{
                        fontSize: 16,
                        color: Colors.primaryText
                    }}>{navigation.state.params.actionTitle}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>:null
        )
    })
};
```

**navigation.state.params.actionTitle** is by default undefined. So on page lode it will not show the headerRight view. I want to display the headerRight view based on some network response from redux. I am handling the redux data in **componentWillReceiveProps** section.

But from **componentWillReceiveProps** if I tried to change the actionTitle then a recursion is happening and whole UI is blocking. By recursion I mean componentWillReceiveProps is called repeatedly. I am setting the navigation state using:--

```
componentWillReceiveProps(props){
  this.props.navigation.setParams({
        actionTitle : "Delete"
  });
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

componentWillReceiveProps is called for every state and props changes, thats why it is re-render as many times. Try to update the navigation title based on your network response .

Check the props for the title change and only update the title if the props contains the network response i.e delete in your case.

```
if(props.header === "Delete") {  // assuming you are passing as header in redux
  this.props.navigation.setParams({
    actionTitle : "Delete"
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make a custom component with redux connected like this

```
// Header.js
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import React from 'react'
import {View, Text} from 'react-native'

    const Header = ({name}) => {
        return (
            <View  style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                <Text>{name}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }

    // REDUX MAPPING
    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
        name: state.auth.name
    })

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Header);
```

and use it in your component as

```
import Header from '../../Components/Header'

// Inside your class

 static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        return {
            headerRight: <Header />,
        }
    }
```